# Is it safe to remove the SSH folder under /etc after uninstalling SSH?

Tags: ssh, security, configuration

I uninstalled SSH via `sudo apt purge ssh`, then deleted the ssh folder under /etc. Is that safe? I just don't want to open a security vulnerability on my PC.

Comment: The `ssh` package is merely a metapackage, an additional step (`sudo apt autoremove --purge) is needed to actually remove the ssh software. This additional step should remove the ssh files in /etc.

Answer (score 1):

The files under `/etc/ssh` are required if you still have the SSH client installed on your system.  If you've removed the SSH client and the SSH server then you don't *need* the files but there's no security vulnerabilities that flat configuration files (text basically) are going to cause.

You *can* remove them, but **I would err on the side of caution and leave them alone** as they won't do any harm or introduce any vulnerabilities - without the `ssh` or `sshd` binaries installed on your system having the leftover host ssh fingerprints and any leftover flat-file (text) configuration data in the folder is not going to introduce a security vulnerability.

---

Looks like I never answered a comment from July 7th, 2022.

**If you simply want to disallow connections to your computer, just put a firewall in place.**  Default rulesets on `ufw` will just disable external connections into your system but permit you to still use the Internet and have outgoing connections.

First, install `ufw` if it isn't already installed: `sudo apt install ufw`

Next, enable `ufw`.  `sudo ufw enable`

You're done, a default ruleset will just protect your system from junk connections coming in to try and connect to your system.

Comment: I deleted the ssh folder already. If I were to just want the client(disabling connecting to my PC), how would I do that?
I believe some of it was rooted in paranoia(I don't know everything about Linux yet), but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: How about the `~/.ssh` folder?

Comment: @user598527 you can remove `~/.ssh` but that's not going to disable connections.  The proper answer here I never circled back on which was "Put a firewall in place" which I'll update my answer for

Answer (score 0):

`/etc` is just the configuration folder and does not contain any executable files. So if you removed/purged the executables, the files under `/etc` persist as arbitrary/meaningless text files.